# How to remove the selected row from my nsmutable array in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a chat application in which when somebody messages you I put a new message string in each cell. For that I am adding the new messages to an array like `[newmessagearrays addObject:event.data];` then after adding that I am reloading the table view, to show in the cells a new message. If you select a cell I am tring to remove that item from my array like `[self.newmessagearrays removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. For the first case it was working fine. When I came back and select the next one it crashes. Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Comment: No, since http://emclstcd.tk

Comment: @ H2CO3i think its because i am trying to remove an index which is not there?

Comment: After removing object are you reloading table or not ??

Comment: @hacker IDK, because [my first comment here].

Comment: @BestCoder yes ofcourse

Comment: @H2CO3 i am sorting my array with the last came first.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying your UITableView's data source, you need to either call `– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `reloadData`.  If that doesn't fix it, post your code and crash logs, because the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: if i remove using this is that index is changed for the remaining element

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. You need to track the indexes of the items you are storing inside the array.